# Sonar 5.4 support qualitygate

Tags: sonarqube-5.4

we just upgrade our Sonar server from 4.5.4 to 5.4 and find out that the `sonar.qualitygate` parameter is not supported any more.

How can we update the quality gate dynamically from the build server - We run Sonar for every feature branch and we have a lot quality gates - and currently we cannot use the correct quality gate.

Thanks , Mor

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36347106/sonar-qualitygate-is-deprecated-in-sonar-qube-5-3-what-is-the-alternative